# load same data with jquery tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

is that posible to load same data with jquery tooltip?
for example i have a data like this.

```
<div class="content"><a href="#"><span id="user_801130021">text1</span></a></div>
<div class="content"><a href="#"><span id="user_801130021">text2</span></a></div>
<div class="content"><a href="#"><span id="user_1301193710">text3</span></a></div>
```

the tooltip only showing for `text1` and `text3` but not showing data for `text2`, i think that because same id there.

here my js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// initialize tooltip
$( " span" ).tooltip({
    track:true,
    open: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.tooltip.css("max-width", "100%");
          var id = this.id;
          var split_id = id.split('_');
          var userid = split_id[1];

          $.ajax({
              url:'fetch_details.php',
              type:'post',
              data:{userid:userid},
              success: function(response){

                  // Setting content option
                  $("#"+id).tooltip('option','content',response);

              }
          });
    }
});

$(" span").mouseout(function(){
    // re-initializing tooltip
    $(this).tooltip();
    $('.ui-tooltip').hide();
});
```

});

my fetch_details.php

```
<?php
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$query = $db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM master_post WHERE id_master_post =".$userid);
$query->execute();
$html = '<div>';
while ($value = $query->fetch()) {
    $information = html_entity_decode ($value['information']);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($information);
    $image = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    $html .= "<img src='".$image."' height='300px' width='250px'>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are not going to be unique as in your code, you can do different things.

#### Class

You can use class instead of id.

Use `<span class="user_801130021">` instead of `<span id="user_801130021">`

You can access them by using basic jQuery selectors : `$('.user_801130021')`

#### HTML5 Data Attributes

Another option is using them as HTML5 data attributes which is so much better in my opinion. Their format is `data-*`.

`<span data-user="user_801130021">`

You can get data-user value by `$('span').data('user')` and change it by `$('span').data('user', value)`

For example, if you changed `id` to `data-user`, you must change `var id = this.id;` to `var id = this.data('user');`. Then everything will be work as it must.

Comment: using class still not working... the id generate from post_id, so im not create it manually. if im using html5 like u say tooltip not showing.

Comment: Change `$("#"+id).tooltip('option','content',response);` to `$("."+id).tooltip('option','content',response);` if you are using class.

Comment: `$('span[data-user="'+ id +'"]').tooltip('option','content',response);` if you are using data-user. There is double quote and single quote after equal mark.

Comment: If it is still not working, please post the final code.

Comment: im edit my question, after using class, image not showing anymore.

Comment: You are not reading my answer correctly. I said 'For example, if you changed id to data-user, you must change `var id = this.id;` to `var id = this.data('user');`'

Comment: im using `class` not `data*`.

Comment: Then use `this.className` instead of `this.id`

Answer (score 0):

i found the trick.

use looping number to create unique id.

here my code.

```
$np = 0;
        while ($value = $query->fetch()) {
<div class="content"><a href="#"><span id="user<?php echo np++ ?>_801130021">text1</span></a></div>
}
```